# Set permission to serial port running Mono

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, mono

I just ported an application to Ubuntu in the Raspberry board, but could not get any response from serial port. I set permissions to Arduino IDE to check if serialport is OK (and now it´s working), but the application I wrote could not get any data from this port, how can I set permissions to this specific application?

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is simply getting an access to com port denied by your mono application, then it may be that your user is not in the dialout group.

To check from a terminal use-:

groups

To add a user to the dial out group-:

sudo adduser user_name dialout

and then log out & back in to take effect.

If it is not this, then you will need to post a bit of your code.